# JSF AjaxBehaviorEvent is not fired

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have `<h:selectManyMenu>` and `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` components called "Select ALL" in my jsf form. When `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` is clicked, all items in `<h:selectManyMenu>` are selected and I can see all of them selected but `valueChangeListener` method is not fired. I tried to put `listener="#{teamController.dummy}"` in `<f:ajax>` tag but does not work. Any solution?

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px; float: right;">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{teamController.selectAll}"
        valueChangeListener="#{teamController.selectAll}"> Select All
        <f:ajax event="click" render="showList" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</div>
<div style="margin: 0px;">
    <p:message for="showList" styleClass="showListRequired">
    </p:message>
    <h:selectManyMenu id="showList" value="#{teamController.selectedList}"
        style="height:200px; width: 280px;" immediate="true"
        required="true" requiredMessage="#{msgs.showListRequired}"
        valueChangeListener="#{teamController.dummy}">
        <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="showList" />    
        <f:selectItems value="#{teamController.showList}" />
    </h:selectManyMenu>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `immediate="true"` property in your `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` to have your valueChangeListener method executed.

Comment: Problem with valueChangeListener in selectManyMenu, not in <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> that works fine.